# Spring ApplicationListener is not receiving events

Tags: java, spring, listener, applicationcontext

I have the following ApplicationListener:

```
package org.mycompany.listeners;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextStartedEvent;

public class MyApplicationListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextStartedEvent> {

  public MyApplicationListener() {
    super();
    System.out.println("Application context listener is created!");
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritDoc}
   */
  public void onApplicationEvent(final ContextStartedEvent event) {
    System.out.println("Context '" + event.getApplicationContext().getDisplayName() + "' is started!");
  }

}
```

And the following bean definition:

```
<bean name="myApplicationListener" class="org.mycompany.listeners.MyApplicationListener" />
```

I can see that bean is created as message from the constructor is printed, but context start event is never recieved. What am I missing?

Comment: Should It have a @Component annotation?

Answer (score 68, accepted):

`ContextStartedEvent` is published when you explicitly invoke `ConfigurableApplicationContext.start()` on the context. If you need an event that is published when context is initialized, use `ContextRefreshedEvent`.

**See also:**

- [3.13.2 Standard and Custom Events](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#context-functionality-events)

Comment: Note that `ContextRefreshedEvent` may be published more than once, and therefore it may be also published before all the beans are initialized (e.g. when using CXF 2.4.2...). However, in most common setup, `ContextRefreshedEvent` will be indeed published only when contexted startup is finished.

Comment: very helpful but this conventions looks inappropriate :(

Answer (score 7):

Since you have no lazy loaded beans (according to you) then you are most likely using events for the wrong reason and probably should use something like [InitializingBean](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html) interface instead:

```
public class MyBean implements InitializingBean {

    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        // ...
    }

}
```

From Spring manual:

> To interact with the container's management of the bean lifecycle, you
>   can implement the Spring InitializingBean and DisposableBean
>   interfaces. The container calls afterPropertiesSet() for the former
>   and destroy() for the latter to allow the bean to perform certain
>   actions upon initialization and destruction of your beans. You can
>   also achieve the same integration with the container without coupling
>   your classes to Spring interfaces through the use of init-method and
>   destroy method object definition metadata.

Source: [Spring Framework - Lifecycle callbacks](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-lifecycle)

Comment: I think the afterPropertiesSet method applies to a single bean, not to the whole spring application context. http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/beans/factory/InitializingBean.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this helps, but I vaguely remember having a similar problem, which was solved by preloading and not lazy loading. Here's a [quick overview](http://www.digizol.com/2008/09/lazy-load-pre-load-beans-spring.html) of both

Comment: I have no lazy-initalized beans in my context.