# How to add a hook to the application context initialization event?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller, applicationcontext

For a regular Servlet, I guess you could declare a [context listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html), but for Spring MVC would Spring make this any easier?

Furthermore, if I define a context listener and then would need to access the beans defined in my `servlet.xml` or `applicationContext.xml`, how would I get access to them?

Answer (score 115, accepted):

[**Spring has some standard events which you can handle.**](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#context-functionality-events)

To do that, you must create and register a bean that implements the `ApplicationListener` interface, something like this:

```
package test.pack.age;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationEvent;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationListener;
import org.springframework.context.event.ContextRefreshedEvent;

public class ApplicationListenerBean implements ApplicationListener {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEvent event) {
        if (event instanceof ContextRefreshedEvent) {
            ApplicationContext applicationContext = ((ContextRefreshedEvent) event).getApplicationContext();
            // now you can do applicationContext.getBean(...)
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

You then register this bean within your `servlet.xml` or `applicationContext.xml` file:

```
<bean id="eventListenerBean" class="test.pack.age.ApplicationListenerBean" />
```

and Spring will notify it when the application context is initialized.

In Spring 3 (if you are using this version), the [`ApplicationListener` class is generic](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) and you can declare the event type that you are interested in, and the event will be filtered accordingly. You can simplify a bit your bean code like this:

```
public class ApplicationListenerBean implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        ApplicationContext applicationContext = event.getApplicationContext();
        // now you can do applicationContext.getBean(...)
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: ok, thanks . it's good to know that spring3 filters the events. I did notice the applicationlistener class before. but its hooks would also be called for RequestHandledEvent.

Comment: Any idea what will happen if you use the annotation stuff and you declare two classes ? Non-annotation ( XML ) and two ? Will they fire in the order declared? thanks ;)

Comment: Just for info, event for context started is ContextStartedEvent
Docs :- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/event/ContextStartedEvent.html

Comment: @Kumar Sambhav: that is correct but the differences must also be mentioned. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5728376/spring-applicationlistener-is-not-receiving-events and here: http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/container/77684-difference-between-contextstartedevent-contextrefreshedevent

Comment: from [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html): *"As of Spring 3.0, an ApplicationListener can generically declare the event type that it is interested in. When registered with a Spring ApplicationContext, events will be filtered accordingly, with the listener getting invoked for matching event objects only."* hence, you can replace the `instanceof` checking by implementing `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>`

Comment: Current [Spring Event Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#context-functionality-events)

Comment: Yes needs to be implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>

Comment: `@Component` needs to be added above the class

Answer (score 100):

Since Spring 4.2 you can use `@EventListener` ([documentation](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2))

```
@Component
class MyClassWithEventListeners {

    @EventListener({ContextRefreshedEvent.class})
    void contextRefreshedEvent() {
        System.out.println("a context refreshed event happened");
    }
}
```

Comment: how do I print properties etc, this method seems to take no params?

Comment: Simply add ContextRefreshedEvent as argument instead of annotation param

Answer (score 6):

Create your annotation

```
  @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    public @interface AfterSpringLoadComplete {
    }
```

Create class

```
    public class PostProxyInvokerContextListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    @Autowired
    ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        ApplicationContext context = event.getApplicationContext();
        String[] names = context.getBeanDefinitionNames();
        for (String name : names) {
            try {
                BeanDefinition definition = factory.getBeanDefinition(name);
                String originalClassName = definition.getBeanClassName();
                Class<?> originalClass = Class.forName(originalClassName);
                Method[] methods = originalClass.getMethods();
                for (Method method : methods) {
                    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(AfterSpringLoadComplete.class)){
                        Object bean = context.getBean(name);
                        Method currentMethod = bean.getClass().getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());
                        currentMethod.invoke(bean);
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Register this class by @Component annotation or in xml

```
<bean class="ua.adeptius.PostProxyInvokerContextListener"/>
```

and use annotation where you wan on any method that you want to run after context initialized, like:

```
   @AfterSpringLoadComplete
    public void init() {}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a single page application on entering URL it was creating a HashMap (used by my webpage) which contained data from multiple databases. 
I did following things to load everything during server start time-

1- Created ContextListenerClass

```
public class MyAppContextListener implements ServletContextListener
    @Autowired

    private  MyDataProviderBean myDataProviderBean; 

    public MyDataProviderBean getMyDataProviderBean() {

        return MyDataProviderBean;

    }

    public void setMyDataProviderBean(MyDataProviderBean MyDataProviderBean) {

        this.myDataProviderBean = MyDataProviderBean;

    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent arg0) {

        System.out.println("ServletContextListener destroyed");

    }


    @Override

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent context) {

        System.out.println("ServletContextListener started");

        ServletContext sc = context.getServletContext();

        WebApplicationContext springContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(sc);

        MyDataProviderBean MyDataProviderBean = (MyDataProviderBean)springContext.getBean("myDataProviderBean");

        Map<String, Object> myDataMap = MyDataProviderBean.getDataMap();

        sc.setAttribute("myMap", myDataMap);

    }
```

2- Added below entry in web.xml

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener> 
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.context.listener.MyAppContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

3- In my Controller Class updated code to first check for Map in servletContext

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String index(@ModelAttribute("model") ModelMap model) {

            Map<String, Object> myDataMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            if (context != null && context.getAttribute("myMap")!=null)
            {

                myDataMap=(Map<String, Object>)context.getAttribute("myMap");
            }

            else
            {

                myDataMap = myDataProviderBean.getDataMap();
            }

            for (String key : myDataMap.keySet())
            {
                model.addAttribute(key, myDataMap.get(key));
            }
            return "myWebPage";

        }
```

With this much change when I start my tomcat it loads dataMap during startTime and puts everything in servletContext which is then used by Controller Class to get results from already populated servletContext .

Answer (score 0):

Please follow below step to do some processing after Application Context get loaded i.e application is ready to serve.

1. Create below annotation i.e

   @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
   @Target(value= {ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE}) 
   public @interface AfterApplicationReady {}

2.Create Below Class which is a listener which get call on application ready state.

```
    @Component
    public class PostApplicationReadyListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationReadyEvent> {

    public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PostApplicationReadyListener.class);
    public static final String MODULE = PostApplicationReadyListener.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationReadyEvent event) {
        try {
            ApplicationContext context = event.getApplicationContext();
            String[] beans = context.getBeanNamesForAnnotation(AfterAppStarted.class);

            LOGGER.info("bean found with AfterAppStarted annotation are : {}", Arrays.toString(beans));

            for (String beanName : beans) {
                Object bean = context.getBean(beanName);
                Class<?> targetClass = AopUtils.getTargetClass(bean);
                Method[] methods = targetClass.getMethods();
                for (Method method : methods) {
                    if (method.isAnnotationPresent(AfterAppStartedComplete.class)) {

                        LOGGER.info("Method:[{} of Bean:{}] found with AfterAppStartedComplete Annotation.", method.getName(), beanName);

                        Method currentMethod = bean.getClass().getMethod(method.getName(), method.getParameterTypes());

                        LOGGER.info("Going to invoke method:{} of bean:{}", method.getName(), beanName);

                        currentMethod.invoke(bean);

                        LOGGER.info("Invocation compeleted method:{} of bean:{}", method.getName(), beanName);
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Exception occured : ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally when you start your Spring application just before log stating application started your listener will be called.

Answer (score 0):

Your bean can also implement `SmartInitializingSingleton.afterSingletonsInstantiated()`. This is one of the possibilities, listed in the Spring documentation (current state: v 6.0.12):
https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/reference/core/beans/factory-nature.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-initializingbean

> For a scenario where expensive post-initialization activity is to be triggered, e.g. asynchronous database preparation steps, your bean should either implement `SmartInitializingSingleton.afterSingletonsInstantiated()` or rely on the context refresh event: implementing `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` or declaring its annotation equivalent `@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)`. Those variants come after all regular singleton initialization and therefore outside of any singleton creation lock.

> Alternatively, you may implement the `(Smart)Lifecycle` interface and integrate with the container’s overall lifecycle management, including an auto-startup mechanism, a pre-destroy stop step, and potential stop/restart callbacks.