# Couchbase Template Config Class

Tags: spring, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I have a Config class for Couchbase as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration{

@Value("${couchbase.serverList:127.0.0.1}")
String IPS;
@Value("${couchbase.disabled}")
boolean disabled;

private static final Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(CouchbaseConfig.class);
@Override
protected List<String> bootstrapHosts() {
    logger.info("Array List for Couch: " + IPS);
    return Arrays.asList(IPS.split(","));

}
```

To make it More Team Friendly i want to add a parameter disabled which allows the Application to still run if one member has not got couchbase  on his local.

Is it possible?

Something like this is present in Normal couchbase configuration.

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    if (disabled)
        return;

    logger.info("Opening couchbase connection.");
    try {
        cluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(Arrays.asList(hosts.split(",")));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a nifty little set of annotations from the `@Conditional` family in Spring 4. This allows you to have Spring consider the annotated method only if the condition described by the annotation is met.

`@Conditional` can be put on a method declaring a `@Bean`, or even on a whole `@Configuration` class. In the later case, all the beans in the configuration as well as component scan annotations will be subject to the condition.

### Do you use `Spring Boot`?

If yes, then good news! There is a lot of `@Conditional` flavors packaged with Spring Boot. One in particular will suit your needs I think: [`@ConditionalOnProperty`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnProperty.html).

### Don't use Spring Boot?

(give it a try :p)

The [`@Conditional` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Conditional.html) is in Spring's core but you have to provide it with a `Condition` implementation class, so it is up to you to code the Condition (not too complicated an interface, but still).

### Spring Older than 4.x?

There is also the older alternative of the [`@Profile` annotation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Profile.html) from Spring 3.1, where you would classify your configuration into profiles and activate one particular profile at runtime, but it is less flexible...

Comment: I would only able to use @Profile  I did some research and was not able came to a Fix resolution. Can you help in this.

Comment: try to annotate your configuration class with `@Profile("couchbase")` for instance. to activate the profile, you'll have to go a different route from the property (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18614849/how-to-set-the-profile-using-application-properties-in-spring). Note that you have to come up with a strategy on how not having Couchbase enabled doesn't break the rest of your app (what if you have services that @Inject a repository for instance?)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
...
@ConditionalOnProperty(prefix = "couchbase", name = "enabled", matchIfMissing = true)
@Configuration
@EnableCouchbaseRepositories
public class CouchbaseConfig extends AbstractCouchbaseConfiguration{
    @Value("${couchbase.serverList:127.0.0.1}")
    String IPS; 

    @Override
    protected List<String> bootstrapHosts() {
        return Arrays.asList(IPS.split(","));

    }
    ...
}
```