# Compute the time taken to load spring beans

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

I have an application that is composed of more than 100 `spring.xml` files. I would like to figure out the amount of time taken for loading all  the `beans` defined in these `spring.xml` files. Please can you let me know how this can  be done? Thank You!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686507/how-to-add-a-hook-to-the-application-context-initialization-event maybe

Answer (score 1):

You can calculate spring beans loading time using test class. Load all your xml files manually (without using annotation - @ContextConfiguration).

```
@Before
public void setup(){
    long then = System.currentTimeMillis();
    ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "com/abc/applicationContext.xml",
            "com/abc/service-context.xml");
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Difference is :"+(now - then));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

long then = System.currentTimeMillis();

// do all your stuff

System.out.println("Milliseconds taken: " + System.currentTimeMillis() - then);

Comment: @PunterVicky wherever you want to being timing things, it isn't that complicated. You're just marking a starting point, then subtracting it from the current time.

Comment: Thanks , but I am not sure where this has to be updated in order to compute the load time for spring beans.