# Spring Boot - Best way to start a background thread on deployment

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application deployed in Tomcat 8.  When the application starts I want to start a worker Thread in the background that Spring Autowires with some dependencies.  Currently I have this :

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class MyServer extends SpringBootServletInitializer {   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Starting application");
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(MyServer.class, args);
        Thread subscriber = new Thread(ctx.getBean(EventSubscriber.class));
        log.info("Starting Subscriber Thread");
        subscriber.start();
    }
```

In my Docker test environment this works just fine - but when I deploy this to my Linux (Debian Jessie, Java 8) host in Tomcat 8 I never see the "Starting Subscriber Thread" message (and the thread is not started).

Comment: So it can run as a standalone server also, without Tomcat.

Comment: and what is calling this `main` in a `tomcat` environment?

Comment: With a method annotated @Bean in MyServer class?

Comment: You are aware of the fact that starting a thread in a EE environment is basically a bad thing to do? Just create a service in spring annotate it with `@Scheduled` and let it run on certain intervals. Or even better why do you need this thread? Generally there are better (and more spring integrated) solutions.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The main method is not called when deploying the application to a non-embedded application server. 
The simplest way to start a thread is to do it from the beans constructor.
Also a good idea to clean up the thread when the context is closed, for example:

```
@Component
class EventSubscriber implements DisposableBean, Runnable {

    private Thread thread;
    private volatile boolean someCondition;

    EventSubscriber(){
        this.thread = new Thread(this);
        this.thread.start();
    }

    @Override
    public void run(){
        while(someCondition){
            doStuff();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy(){
        someCondition = false;
    }

}
```

Comment: It is not possible to add @Bean on the class level, see https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html

Comment: Good point, I have changed it to `@Component` instead, although you can register the bean however you want really.

Comment: Doing significant work in the constructor, such as starting a thread makes it very hard to test the object.  The reply from Snickers3192 should be the accepted answer

Comment: @xpmatteo Fair point. If you want to be able to construct the object without starting the thread, you could use a `@PostConstruct` annotation.

Answer (score 5):

You could have a bean which impelements `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` It's `onApplicationEvent` will be called just start your thread there if it hasn't been started already. I think you want the ApplicationReadyEvent by the way.

**Edit**
[How to add a hook to the application context initialization event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686507/how-to-add-a-hook-to-the-application-context-initialization-event)

```
@Component
public class FooBar implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    Thread t = new Thread();

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        if (!t.isAlive()) {
            t.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know SO frowns upon examples in links rather than answers, but [here's spring's guide to using ApplicationListnener](https://spring.io/blog/2015/02/11/better-application-events-in-spring-framework-4-2)

Comment: There you go @KCK

Answer (score 0):

Starting a Thread manually is probably not the best way to do it. Instead, use Springs [Task execution and Scheduling](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/integration.html#scheduling) functionionality.