# is there any way to notify the user that the springboot service has successfully launched?

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot

I've created a spring-boot service that connect with mongoDB offering an APIRest to the front end application. When i run the JAR file it took too long to provide the service. So i wanted to know if there is a away to notify the user that service is ready.

Comment: See the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686507/how-to-add-a-hook-to-the-application-context-initialization-event). You need to handle the ContextRefreshedEvent. You can, maybe, send a websocket notification in the handler.

Comment: What's the main role for this ContextRefreshedEvent?

Comment: It's an event that gets published by Spring when the ApplicationContext is initialized or refreshed. See section 1.15.2 [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#context-introduction).