# How to integrate a self-test into Spring-Integration?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I want to start a selftest after spring-integration is started. My first approach was to start it after the setup of the integration flow:

```
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
@EnableIntegrationManagement
@IntegrationComponentScan
public class FlowConfig {
...
    @PostConstruct
    public void startSelfTest() {
        SelfTest selfTest = new SelfTest(rezeptConfig, dataSource, archiveClient);
        selfTest.run();
    }
...
}
```

This does not work because when the test was started the tables in the database were missing because liquibase was not yet started. I guess the liquibase scripts would be started after initialization.

Any ideas what is the best place to start a selftest?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the best practice to do low-level resources interaction is when everything is initialized in the application context already. And that is the phase when beans are started according their `SmartLifecycle` implementation.

So, what I suggest to revise your solution to be done from some `SmartLifecycle.start()`.

That's exactly what we do everywhere around in Spring Integration.
(Be sure that we talk exactly about the same Spring Integration: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration)

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-factory-lifecycle-processor

Answer (score 0):

just guessing, what about `onApplicationEvent` event in ApplicationListener  ? This is called when Spring is initialized and ready.

E.g. check this one [How to add a hook to the application context initialization event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8686507/how-to-add-a-hook-to-the-application-context-initialization-event)

Comment: I'm not sure if the liquibase bean is started after the context is initialized but you're right, this would be the correct place to start the Selftest.

Answer (score 0):

The Liquibase bean which is responsible to create and update the DB tables are started after my Selftest. One solution is to use @DependsOn togehther with the @Bean annotation:

```
    @Bean
    @DependsOn("liquibase")
    public SelfTest startSelfTest() {
        SelfTest selfTest = new SelfTest(rezeptConfig, dataSource, archiveClient);
        selfTest.run();
        return selfTest;
    }
```

Now the Selftest is started after Liquibase.